# julia - Why do single functions in vector passed as arguments not work

Tags: julia

I have a demo here of passing functions as parameters to another function.  But its not working in all cases.

The issue is im getting: `::Vector{typeof(is_valid_wallet_address)}`  instead of `Vector{Function}`

```
function validate(data::NamedTuple, field::Symbol, validators::Vector{Function})
    for validator in validators
        validator(data[field])
    end
end

function is_valid_wallet_address(address)
    # Validation logic for wallet address
end

function is_valid_wallet_signature(signature)
    # Validation logic for wallet signature
end

data = (wallet_address="123456789", wallet_signature="abcdef")

# works 
validate(data, :wallet_address, [is_valid_wallet_address, is_valid_wallet_signature])

# doesn't work
validate(data, :wallet_address, [is_valid_wallet_address])
validate(data, :wallet_address, [is_valid_wallet_address, is_valid_wallet_address])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather common confusion related to contra-variant/covariant/invariant subtypes. Julia goes with the invariant subtyping idea. A good reference is: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-parametric-composite-types.

To get over this difficulty, the function `validate` can be defined to take any **subtype** of Function and then all the calls work as expected:

```
function validate(data::NamedTuple, field::Symbol, validators::Vector{<:Function})
    for validator in validators
        validator(data[field])
    end
end
```

Note the `<:` before `Function`.